# Reload UITableView except one section of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with multiple sections.
Now I want to reload all sections of tableView except the first one (because it's static and doesn't change).

I now I can reload sections by this method:

```
reloadSections(IndexSet, with: UITableView.RowAnimation)
```

but it requires the number of sections and in my app this is dynamic and changes in time.
I can only say reload whatever exist after first section.

I thought I should define a `IndexSet` somehow like this:

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:(NSUInteger[]){1, ... } length:???];
```

and I don't know how can I do that!

Any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

> **update**

This is the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    // Inbox Segment
    if (self.selectedIndex == 0) {
        if (self.inboxArray.count > 0) {
            return self.inboxArray.count + 2;
        }
    }

    // Sent Segment
    else if (self.selectedIndex == 1) {
        if (self.sentArray.count > 0) {
            return self.sentArray.count + 2;
        }
    }

    // Outbox Segment
    else if (self.selectedIndex == 2) {
        if (self.outboxArray.count > 0) {
            return self.outboxArray.count + 2;
        }
    }

    // Spam Segment
    else if (self.selectedIndex == 3) {
        if (self.spamArray.count > 0) {
            return self.spamArray.count + 2;
        }
    }

    // Trash Segment
    else if (self.selectedIndex == 4) {
        if (self.trashArray.count > 0) {
            return self.trashArray.count + 2;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you know how many sections you have if you use a sectioned tableView since i guess you implemented numberOfSectionsInTableView: ?

Comment: If I understood your issue, `tableView.reloadData()` should be ok, reloading the first section is ok if its static. This will be easier...

Comment: @Teetz I have some dynamic arrays with different sizes, in different situations one array make the number of sections.

Comment: Another point, you could iterate through all sections in the table view but not the first one (I assume that you could recognize it because you have to mention it in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method) and then reload them.

Comment: @AhmadF it's not ok, because every time I reload the tableView, the first section blinks.

Comment: Well, what about trying: `UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
}`?

Comment: @AhmadF still blinks

Comment: @arash what about moving static stuff on the first section to the tableview header? That way you can `reloadData` without it blinking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the amount of sections:

```
NSIndexSet *sectionsIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, self.sections.count - 1)]
[self.tableView reloadSections:sectionsIndexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Swift:

```
let sectionsIndexSet = IndexSet(1..<sections.count)
tableView.reloadSections(sectionsIndexSet, with: .none)
```

Comment: Now that you changed the answer it works fine of course. ;)